# Do Ants have a sense of Direction?

Tags: physiology, ant

Do ants understand which way is up or down?

Could they differentiate between uphill and downhill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually No.

Amazingly there is this paper published on the motions on Ants which says:

> The isotropic distribution of average speed appears as a surprising
>   result since it would be expected, for instance, that ants progressing
>   uphill should be slower than when moving downhill. For instance, Seidl
>   et al. found lower speeds on steeper inclines in desert ants moving
>   uphill, but indicate that desert ants progressing downhill displayed
>   high velocities [42]. **This is in contrast with our finding with Lasius
>   niger in the present set-up where the velocity showed no dependency to
>   the walking direction, even for the steepest inclination.** However,
>   Wohlgemuth et al. report, also in the desert ant, that speed was
>   reduced in both their uphill and downhill channels (+540 ) compared to
>   their flat channel, thereby excluding metabolic cost as a reliable
>   means to gauge walked distance on various inclines [28]. In an attempt
>   to determine the effects of inclination on the gross metabolic cost of
>   locomotion in leaf-cutter ants, Holt & Askew report that ants
>   travelled the fastest on a horizontal plane, and indeed moderated
>   their speed with the inclination, both on the incline and the decline.
>   They suggest that ants adapt their behavior so as to keep their
>   metabolic rate constant despite changing mechanical demands.

Source: [How Do Ants Make Sense of Gravity? A Boltzmann Walker Analysis of Lasius niger Trajectories on Various Inclines](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0076531)